# Does $\sum (2n)!/(n!) $ converge p-adically

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers, power-series

Does $\sum (2n)!/(n!) $ converge p-adically, I have worked out  $v_p((2n)!) \leqslant 2n/(p-1) $ similarly $v_p((n)!) \leqslant n/(p-1) $

I want to prove this using the result that it converges p-adically iff $v_p()$ tends to infinity as n tends to infinity, I'm not familiar with p-adic absolute values so was wondering if this can be done without using them

Comment: This follows immediately from the formula $v_p(n!)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\lfloor n/p^k\rfloor$.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach:

$\dfrac{(2n)!}{n!}=n!×\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}=n!×\binom{2n}{n}.$

So

$v_p\left(\dfrac{(2n)!}{n!}\right)\ge v_p(n!)\ge \dfrac{n}{p-1}-\log_pn-1.$

Answer (score 1):

You again. Use my answer here :

[Determining whether ${p^{n-2} \choose k}$ is divisible by $p^{n-k -2}$ for $1 \le k < n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1127894/determining-whether-pn-2-choose-k-is-divisible-by-pn-k-2-for-1-l/1127922#1127922)

as it gives the value of $v_p(n!)$ for any $n$. Then plug $k$ in $n$, and $2k$ in $n$, and see...